# Rolling back transactions programatically in Grails

Tags: grails, transactions, grails-orm

I have the following code code wherein I try to save a user then send a "click this link to confirm your account" email

```
User.withTransaction { TransactionStatus status ->

    try {
        Role userRole = Role.createCriteria().get {
            eq 'authority', 'USER_ROLE'
        }

        user = user.save(failOnError: true)
        UserRole.create user, userRole

        // sends an email using the Grails mail plugin
        sendRegistrationEmail(username, randomPassword)
        redirect action: 'listUsers'

    } catch (ex) {
        status.rollbackOnly
    }
}
```

I sent the email within the transaction, because if an exception is thrown during the email-sending I want the transaction to be rolled back. However I tested this out (by deliberately providing invalid mail server credentials) and the transaction does not get rolled back when an exception is thrown.

If I replace:

```
sendRegistrationEmail(username, randomPassword)
```

with:

```
throw new Exception()
```

then the transaction does get rolled back, so I'm assuming this is because the exception the occurs when a mail is sent is in a different thread and the transaction has already committed by the time this exception is thrown, is this correct?

Is there a way that a can transactionally save the user and send the email, i.e. guarantee that the user is only saved if the email is sent successfully?

### Update

I should have explained why I don't want to save the user if the email is not sent. The reason is that the email contains a "confirm your account" link, so if this email is not sent they won't be able to complete the registration process and won't be able to attempt to register again (if the user is saved) because there's a unique constraint on the username.

Comment: how are you sending the mail? and is it synchronous or asynchronous.

Comment: This code is in a controller? And `sendRegistrationEmail` is in service or is a controller method? A key is that controllers are **not** transactional, but services are. If you mix both you can have problems.

Comment: @SérgioMichels the code is wrapped in `User.withTransaction{}` so it is transactional even though it's in a controller

Comment: @user2264997 the email is sent synchronously

Comment: @Don Yes, I was talking about the default, without using withTransaction. Even if you make the controller action transactional, a better place to put this logic is in a service.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question:- *Is there a way that a can transactionally save the user and send the email, i.e. guarantee that the user is only saved if the email is sent successfully?*

As mentioned by @Sergio Michels, yes there is a more efficient way to use the service classes as below:-

You should have to `throw` an exception out of the transaction to automatically rollback the transaction. I normally do this in `service` layer which is by default transactional. I have to throw the Exception out of Service layer to controller or which ever end point.

For example:

```
def someServiceMethod{
        Role userRole = Role.createCriteria().get {
            eq 'authority', 'USER_ROLE'
        }

        user = user.save(failOnError: true)
        UserRole.create user, userRole

        // sends an email using the Grails mail plugin
        sendRegistrationEmail(username, randomPassword)

        //Rethrown out to controller automatically, 
        //which results in roll back of transaction
}

def sendRegistrationEmail(username, randomPassword){
    throw new Error() //will rollback the transaction
}
```

In your case, make sure you are not catching the Exception inside `sendRegistrationEmail`. If you are, then you have to re-throw to the caller.

PS:- I have the same implementation, but I eat the exception if there is any problem in sending mail, instead of roll back, because the problem is with mail service and not in my User saving service, why should the user suffer. :-)

**UPDATE:-**
Talking about your approach if you have the code in a controller and using `withTransaction`. In your approach, if you are using the Hibernate session anywhere else to persist some other data apart from the logic you have in your question, then you would need to clear the session in the catch block otherwise User data would get `flushed` to database in subsequent operations.

```
catch(ex){
  object.discard()
  status.rollbackOnly()
}
```

*Second Try*
You can try wrapping the new thread you spun `withTransaction` and see if all the transactions gets rolled back.

**Inference:-**
Not to handle transactions as boiler plate code, it is convenient to handle transaction `decleratively` in service than programmatically in anywhere else.

Comment: I've updated my question to answer your PS. I shouldn't have to throw the exception to rollback the transaction because in my `catch` block I call `status.rollbackOnly`, which should also rollback the transaction.

Comment: The difference between your example and mine is that everything is happening in the same thread. If you change your implementation of `sendRegistrationEmail` to `Thread.start { Thread.sleep(3000); throw new Exception() }` I think you'll see the same problem I'm having.

Comment: Also, by default, transactions do not get rolled back for checked exceptions like `Exception`, only for unchecked exceptions (subclasses of `RuntimeException`)

Comment: Agree, I was hasty in one point. I actually throw a business `Error` in my project, not an `Exception`.